# Filter data (Not In) based on condition within two data sets in Google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-query-language

Have employee data set with status active and relieved. And the second data set has the time they have reported to the office. Trying to achieve the names of employee who are absent for the day using one formula. I have attached the images for easy understanding. Please find the sheet wherein I have created sample data and formula which I have used. Trying to achieve it using one array formula or query

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have achieved it using Filter and Match

```
{"Absent For the Day";FILTER((query(importrange("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM","empdata!A2:B30"),"select Col1 where Col2='Active'")),ISERROR(MATCH((query(importrange("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM","empdata!A2:B30"),"select Col1 where Col2='Active'")),A2:A20,0)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Absent For the Day", ""; 
 SPLIT(FILTER(empdata!A2:A, empdata!B2:B="active", 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(empdata!A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A))))&"♦Absent", "♦")})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: as the emp data is in another worksheet in actual, used import range in place of
 empdata!A2:A, empdata!B2:B="active" replaced it with below. But it is not working

`(query(importrange("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM","empdata!A2:B30"),"select Col1 where Col2='Active'") ,(query(importrange("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM","empdata!A2:B30"),"select Col1 where Col2='Active'") `

Comment: @Kanted I see. in that case it would need to be: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Absent For the Day", ""; 
 SPLIT(FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM", "empdata!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 
  where lower(Col2) = 'active'", 0), QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM", "empdata!A2:B"), 
 "select Col2 
  where lower(Col2) = 'active'", 0)="active", 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM", "empdata!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 
  where lower(Col2) = 'active'", 0), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A))))&"♦Absent", "♦")})`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsw49.png or try the shorter answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Absent For the Day", ""; 
 SPLIT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Dj7agceCBS_aCm2GVm4EQHqS8_wQYifoKLMcA0fv4fM", "empdata!A2:B"), 
 "select Col1 
  where lower(Col2) = 'active' 
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A)&"'", 0)&"♦Absent", "♦")})
```

[image: 0]